# Android preference inputType phone default value is a decimal value instead of a string

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an Android application using default values from the Preferences Android framework.
It all works fine except for phone numbers (defined with android:inputType="phone" in preferences.xml).

The phone numbers get treated as numeric value so if I go to the preferences screen to see the default values I see

> 3.3631241E10

for the value defined in preferences.xml as

```
android:defaultValue="+33631241234"
```

To avoid this problem, I have used values from strings.xml defining the default values in preferences.xml like this :

```
android:defaultValue="+33631241234
```

It works ... but I don't like it: that's a source of problem as I need to redefine the same phone number for each language used ! !

I must be doing something wrong as I haven't found anyone else with the same problem on internet however I don't see what I am doing wrong ! !

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> that's a source of problem as I need to redefine the same phone number for each language used

you don't - when the text is absent for a language the default is used - [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) :

> Whenever the application runs in a locale for which you have not provided locale-specific text, Android will load the default strings from res/values/strings.xml.

Comment: Yep, you are right ... I got a bit carried away.
Still, this is not an ideal solution: surely I am doing something wrong ! I must not be the only one using phone number in the preferences.

Comment: @user3095955: api version ?

Comment: Android v. 2.2 ! (I used to be named as user3095955)

Comment: @ComputingFroggy:  ok - try removing the + (+33631241234 --> 33631241234) - still treated as double ?